# M2 - Lots of product attributes and sets

Tags: magento2, attributes, product-attribute, attribute-set

We have a new webshop with photo camera's and all the accessories. We have 25+ attribute sets and the attributes sets have specific attributes (30+).

For example, a camera has the attribute set "Camera" in that attribute set there are 30+ attributes. You can see an example of the exact same thing here: https://www.fotokonijnenberg.nl/canon-eos-2000d-18-135mm-f3-5-5-6-is-stm-1
On the right you see all the attributes like i need them.

Is there a way to manage all those sets and attributs? On the front-end we must show the specific attributs also per product.

Regards,

Comment: What do you mean by "manage"? Are you asking where in the admin panel do you manage this data? or are you asking how to call and display this data on the frontend (for product page, etc)?

Comment: Hi @wesleywmd I know how to display it on the front-end but isn't there an easier way to manage all those different attributes or maybe another way to add these specifications to a product?

Comment: Which part are you finding hard? Managing the attributes themselves or managing the products values for those attributes? Since you are already using attributes sets, it appears that your managing that part correctly. So I assume the issues are with inputting the volume of data. In which case, I could suggest using an import file to create products with all the values needed.

Comment: Hi @wesleywmd I think it's the only way to manage all those specifications through the attributes. But I thought maybe there is some kind of extension which you allows to manage them easier and showing them on the front-end with headings etc.